System freezes while working
I have a problem in the new Ubuntu version 24. When the system is working، it suddenly freezes and shuts down.
None of the resources is used and all of them are normal.

read [ask] the [edit] your question accordingly.

Please provide enough information for the community to be able to help you, for example: write the output of journalctl with help from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181067/how-to-read-dmesg-from-previous-session-dmesg-0

Please edit your question and state which Ubuntu release you are using. There is nothing like "Ubuntu 24". The Ubuntu release numbering consists always of four numbers separated by a dot, e.g. 22.04. In case you use Ubuntu Core, which uses indeed a 2-digit numbering like e.g. Ubuntu Core22, please explicitly state that you use Ubuntu Core.

Does this answer your question? What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?

My  particular last resort solution for system freezing is
Alt+PrtScr+B
This reboots, so it may help your problem.
There may be a better solution. If so, I look forward to reading it.

This belongs in your Question (click [edit]). It is NOT an answer.

@waltinator Salvadorfreeman did not ask the main question.
